# Tracking access to a page

Tags: routes

I have the following defined, the callback tech_incentive_page performs some logic and then renders the result in a page.tpl.php.

```
function tech_incentive_menu() {
  $items['technician-briefs/tech_incentive'] = array(
    'title' => 'Tech Incentive',
    'page callback' => 'tech_incentive_page',
    'access arguments' => array('Tech Incentive Page'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

The question I have is how do I track page access to that url technician-briefs/tech_incentive.

Cheers

Comment: Do you need more than what the standard/core Statistics module (http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/statistics) provides?

Comment: Standard core is what I was looking to use.

Comment: So how can I do this?

Comment: Enable that module and that will provide a track menu tab that will show you access statistics about any nodes.  You can also look at reports about recent hits system wide on a daily and historical basis, etc.

Comment: I have already done this but it only tracks nodes not pages using hook_menu()

Comment: Solved here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75404/how-do-i-record-hook-menu-access-statistics