# How do I record hook_menu() access statistics

Tags: routes, nodes

I have a standard menu hook function in a custom module which links to example.com/foo/bar, how do I record access statistics for this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no build in stat counter for this. Here is a workaround:

```
<?php 
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['foo/bar'] = array(
    'title' => 'example', 
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_foo_bar', 
    'access callback' => 'mymodule_foo_bar_access_with_stat_counter',
    'access arguments' => array('Something', 'Something else'),
  );
}

function mymodule_foo_bar_access_with_stat_counter($something, $something_else) {
  //Log your stats here!
  // goddess_logs_stats_here($something, $soemthing_else);
}
```